# 3PAR 7400 cli setup

Tags: linux-networking, command-line-interface, hp, storage-area-network, 3par

Unfortunatelly we don't have a GUI so we use cli.

How to allocate physical disk space to free space?
I tried servicemag, admithw,admitpd cmd but freespace (showspace) is equal 0

```
3PAR01 cli% showsys

    ---------------(MB)----------------
   ID -Name- ---Model---- -Serial- Nodes Master TotalCap AllocCap FreeCap FailedCap
35055 3PAR01 HP_3PAR 7400 0            2      0  3348480  1995776 1352704         0


3PAR01 cli% showspace
--Estimated(MB)---
RawFree UsableFree
      0          0
PAR01 cli% showpd
                           ---Size(MB)---- ----Ports----             
Id CagePos Type RPM State    Total    Free A      B      Capacity(GB)
 0 0:0:0   FC    15 normal  278528   81920 1:0:1* 0:0:1           300
 1 0:1:0   FC    15 normal  278528   80896 1:0:1  0:0:1*          300
 2 0:2:0   FC    15 normal  278528   89088 1:0:1* 0:0:1           300
 3 0:3:0   FC    15 normal  278528   89088 1:0:1  0:0:1*          300
 4 0:4:0   FC    15 normal  278528   87040 1:0:1* 0:0:1           300
 5 0:5:0   FC    15 normal  278528   86016 1:0:1  0:0:1*          300
 6 0:21:0  FC    10 normal  838656  418816 1:0:1* 0:0:1           900
 7 0:13:0  FC    10 normal  838656  419840 1:0:1  0:0:1*          900
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 8 total                   3348480 1352704     


3PAR01 cli% showld
Id Name          RAID -Detailed_State- Own SizeMB UsedMB Use Lgct LgId WThru MapV
 0 admin.usr.0      1 normal           0/1   5120   5120 V      0  ---     N    Y
 1 admin.usr.1      1 normal           1/0   5120   5120 V      0  ---     N    Y
 2 .srdata.usr.0    1 normal           0/1  40960  40960 V      0  ---     N    Y
 3 .srdata.usr.1    1 normal           1/0  40960  40960 V      0  ---     N    Y
 4 log0.0           1 normal           0/-  20480      0 log    0  ---     Y    N
 5 log1.0           1 normal           1/-  20480      0 log    0  ---     Y    N
 6 pdsld0.0         1 normal           0/1   1024      0 P,F    0  ---     Y    N
 7 pdsld0.1         1 normal           0/1   8192      0 P      0  ---     Y    N
 8 pdsld0.2         1 normal           1/0   8192      0 P      0  ---     Y    N
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9                                         150528  92160 


3PAR01 cli% showcpg
                                       --------------(MB)--------------
               ----Volumes---- -Usage- -- Usr --- -- Snp --- -- Adm ---
Id Name  Warn% VVs TPVVs TDVVs Usr Snp Total Used Total Used Total Used
 0 FC_r1     -   0     0     0   0   0     0    0     0    0     0    0
 1 FC_r5     -   0     0     0   0   0     0    0     0    0     0    0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 total                         0   0     0    0     0    0     0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 cages before anything will work.  5 is recommended if you want to do RAID 5.  If you have your availability set to "cage" and not "magazine" it will bomb out because there aren't enough cages.

Also, Mismatching Spindle speeds is ok, but it will separate the two speeds into separate pools.